# Convert fql query using JOIN parameter sql

Tags: mysql, sql, facebook-fql

i have this code here which permits me to extract friends who liked a specific page, but i need to extract friends that don't like a certain page.

Here is the code:

```
$users = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => "SELECT uid, first_name, pic_small FROM user WHERE uid IN(
    SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id='411133928921438' AND uid IN (
        SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
    ))"));
```

How am i supposed to get something like this using OUTER JOIN OR SMTH :

```
$users = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query',
            'query' => "SELECT uid, first_name, pic_small FROM user WHERE uid NOT IN(
        SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id='411133928921438' AND uid IN (
            SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
        ))"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it doesn't support OUTER JOIN or NOT IN, try doing this (not sure if it's the best way but it should work)

```
$likes = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => "SELECT uid, first_name, pic_small FROM user WHERE uid IN(
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id='411133928921438' AND uid IN (
    SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
))"));

$allfriends = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => "SELECT uid, first_name, pic_small FROM user WHERE uid IN (
    SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
)"));

// Loop through the rows
// I think there is a page where you can test FQL at developers.facebook.com, I'll see if I can find it on my phone so I can see what the JSON response looks like and fix this code, in the mean while see if this works

// Yeah so the code does this:
// Loop through each item in the $allfriends result, (put the contents of the row into the $friend variable
foreach( $allfriends as $friend )
{  
   // This bit I need to change, this is supposed to look in the $likes array to see if the UID is present, but it will be comparing the uid against the whole object - need to tweak this
   if( !in_array($friend['uid'], $likes) ) 
   {
       // Each friend that doesn't like the page should hit this part of the loop
       echo $friend['uid'];
   }                 
}
```

Disclaimer - it's been about 5 years since I used PHP, and ages since I've touched FQL - let me know if anything works/doesn't work (I'll be surprised if it does :D)

Comment: thanks for the answer... yeah i know there is not a outer join in FQL but i thought i could reach this through doing an outer join...

hey but faebook doesn't allow NOT IN parameter..

Comment: Ah ok - I see, didn't know it didn't support NOT IN - not sure if you can do it then - you might need to select them all and filter the ones you want out in software...

Comment: Can you please tell me how am i supposed to do it? through php or something?

Comment: I suggest doing two queries - one to get all your friends, and one to get all the friends who like the page, then use PHP to find all users who are in friends who are not in the 'like' list. I'll update the answer

Comment: yes please, because i understand the logic, but i'm no good with writing the code...

Comment: I've updated the answer - tell me if that works or if not (and what errors you get) - I can't test as I'm at work and I have no access to FB. Also if you can post the JSON response from FB, I can't remember what the structure looks like (so the 'data' indexers in my code are a guess)

Comment: Hey thanks for helping me out :)
i used the code but it says this error on this line: 
foreach( $allfriends['data'] as $friend )
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Try without the ['data'] - the JSON might be not what I remember

Comment: Can you please update the answer? Because i know i'll be doing something wrong and i don't want to bother you again :)
You helped me enough!

Comment: Haha no problem, I will update - but no guarantee it works - if it doesn't work I can help you when I get home (about 19:00 GMT)

Comment: hey charleh :) 
Thanks , you've done enough, it's my job to go deep into the situation right now :)

Comment: hey charlie, thanks for the help, it already makes visible all friends Id, it doesn't select only the friends that don't like the page... anyways, you've been of a great help :) I'll look into it now!

Thank you :)